# CakePHP 2.x translation fallback

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, cakephp-2.x

I need to have fallback in translation.

If I have 2 translations ex.: 'eng' and 'es'
Some records have both translations and some only one or none.
I hoped that if I do it this way:

```
$this->Post->locale = ['es', 'eng'];
$results = $this->Post->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('Post.id' => $id)
));
```

I'll get 'es' translation and if 'es' is not available I'll get 'eng'.
but this does not seem to work.
If I set 'locale' to a single value 'eng' or 'es' it works fine, but when I set $this->locale = ['es', 'eng'];
It seems to be ignored and no translation is taken into the result, just data from model table.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and did not find a sufficient solution, so I used the following workaround:

```
        if (!isset($data['Page']['content'])) {
            // TRANSLATION NOT AVAILABLE or empty content -> take default lang
            $this->Page->locale = Configure::read('Page.default_language');
            $data = $this->Page->find('first', $options);
            if (!isset($data['Page'])) {
            // Not even the default translation found
                throw new NotFoundException();
            } 
        }
```

Remarks: The field "content" is the one being translated with the Translate Behaviour.

Comment: Yes you can do it this way manually for each data row, but I would like to use such fallback when querying more than one row - and would like to receive each row with first available translation.